# Increase Specificity of a model using SMOTE arguments from DMwR package in R when training data is unbalanced

Tags: classification, r, class-imbalance, smote

I'm working on a binary classification problem and training data which I'm using is unbalanced.

I used `SMOTE` function from `DMwR` package in R to balance the data and then used gbm to train on the data.

I used different values of arguments `perc.over` and `perc.under` and got following results:

```
      Sensitivity Specificity perc.over perc.under
 1:   0.5778939 0.759237187       100         90
 2:   0.8529533 0.425506555       200         90
 3:   0.7081825 0.632896305       100        100
 4:   0.9794145 0.103694875       400        100
 5:   0.9840695 0.070321812       600        100
 6:   0.9920348 0.050059595       800        100
 7:   0.9993276 0.004767580      1000        100
 8:   0.9933278 0.028605483      1200        100
 9:   0.9129513 0.270560191       200        200
10:   0.9997931 0.001191895      1000        300
```

So, values in first row gave best Specificity.
I'm more interested in increasing Specificity of a model. Is there a general thumb rule to get best possible values of `perc.over` and `perc.under` for a specific data set?
So that model would be just trained once using best values of  `perc.over` and `perc.under`.

Comment: No , Generally based on your data perc.over and perc.under will be changed.It is not constant for the different data sets.
Also try using the ROSE package also and check the results

Comment: Tried `ROSE` package, didn't get consistent results using that. I know `perc` values will get changed with different data sets. What's the best way to get the best possible values of `perc` for different data sets. By best, I mean with which best balanced accuracy can be achieved.

Comment: u need to try which model ML are using and which patter r u using...like wise

Comment: Didn't get what you're saying. What do you mean by which model ML are using and patter?

Comment: if u use xgboost..there is one parameter u can mention which handles the data imbalance problem, the same way based on which methodology or which algorithm u r going to choose

Comment: Oh ok. I have tried many models like random forest, ada boost, gbm, decision trees. Had tried xgboost few months back. Didn't know it has a parameter for imbalance. WOuld give it a shot. If you can share some example code. Would be great.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85746/discussion-between-samadhi-and-sai-saran).